# Symfony Doctrine Returns Empty Object

Tags: php, symfony, vuejs2

I'm trying to return a specific row in my table using Doctrine in conjunction with Symfony 2 and Vue 2. Here is the code I'm using to achieve this.

```
/**
 * Get all children of the administrator
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function getChildrenAction() {

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$records = $em->getRepository('TestUserBundle:NameOfEntity')-> 
findOneBy(array('id' => 123456));

return new JsonResponse($records);

}
```

My problem is that on the front-end, I always end up with an empty object such as {}, and can't do anything with that. Now I know this is returning the instance of that User, but I want all the data associated with that user in the table row on the front-end, so that I can use it to show specific user details. I know how to pass specific parts of the object, such as Id by tacking on "->id" or "->getId()", but have no clue how to get the whole object. Any help with this, or a gentle shove in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't `$records` be just `$record` as it's `findOneBy`.  I would try outputting the record with `print_r` or the like, then you can isolate the problem to the `findby` or to the `json` encoding parts.  If that makes sense.

Comment: Hi there! You are right, it'd be better to call it record rather than records if I'm trying to return one object, but earlier I was doing something where I was returning multiple records, either way, the name doesn't make a difference, as long as it's the same name in the JsonResponse. Anyways, I've tried to dump, var_dump, or use print_r, but it doesn't work like it's supposed to, since the front-end of the application is in vue.

Comment: you can always write it to a file using `file_put_contents({filename}, var_dump($result, true).PHP_EOL);`  the second argument of var_export returns instead of outputting directly.

Comment: Interesting, I will look into that, thank you for the help!

Comment: Sure, it's a little trick I learned for dealing with things like web hook endpoints or command line scripts that run from cron where the output isn't always accessible.  One issue with Var Export is it's not circular reference safe.  I wouldn't mention this but I have had issues with Doctrine with circular reference printing.   If you get a out of memory error when trying to debug, you can use my debugger from [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Debug) it can also be installed via composer with `evo/debug` and it's circular safe.

Comment: With my debugger you can use `$Debug->export($var)` or `$Debug->varExport($var)` to get return instead of output. it has a few other nice features, like showing constants value, private or protected properties and you can show as much of them or little by setting flags for it.  It has depth and circular reference protection, and can output in HTML or plain text.

Answer (score 0):

`FindOneBy` method returns a entity object according with the criteria given, if you want get that data from your view (twig template)

```
function doAction(){

  //...
  $this->render('some_template.html.twig', ['record' => $record ]);
}
```

some_template.html.twig

```
{{ dump(record) }}
```

Or if you wish return a response without a template, you could use `JsonResponse` class.

```
return new JsonResponse($records);
```

The `JsonResponse` class sets the Content-Type header to application/json and encodes your data to JSON when needed.